# Running 3 miles in 20 minutes, how many miles can one run in 50 minutes?

Tags: arithmetic

Maria can run 3 miles in 20 minutes.  At this rate, how many miles could she run in 50 minutes?

I have tried dividing 3 by 20 to get the unit rate.

Comment: **Hint:** $\quad50=20+20+10$.

Comment: @Lucian: Why not? Simple but effective. +1 for you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, and then multiply by that 0.15 by 50 to get the total distance of 7.5 miles.

Answer (score 2):

Using the basic relationship $t\cdot r=d$, we have $$\require{cancel}\underbrace{50\cancel{\textrm{ min}}}_{\textrm{time}}\cdot\underbrace{\left(\frac{3\textrm{ miles}}{20\cancel{\textrm{ min}}}\right)}_{\textrm{rate}}=\underbrace{7.5\textrm{ miles}}_{\textrm{distance}}$$